# Relativity of Simultaneity - Is there ever a Preferential Frame of Reference?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, observers

A regular description of the paradox involves a train travelling through a tunnel which is fitted with doors at either end which can be raised and lowered. In their respective rest frames the length of the train is measured, by an observer on board, at 500 metres and the length of the tunnel is measured, by a ground-based observer, at 300 metres.

Ground Observer measures the train travelling at such speed that gamma factor = 2 and therefore measures the train length, due to contraction, as 250 metres and concludes that the train will fit in the tunnel. He activates a control which causes the gates at either end to simultaneously close and instantly open again while the train is inside the tunnel and the train passes through.

Train Observer measures the tunnel approaching at such speed that gamma factor = 2 and measures the tunnel length as 150 metres. He, therefore, concludes that the train can not fit within the tunnel but, nevertheless, it passes safely through, despite the fact that he observes the doors closing and opening again.

The solution given is that while Ground Observer measured the doors closing and opening as being simultaneous events, Train Observer did not, and measured them as occurring at different times. The Theory of Special Relativity asserts that both observers are equally entitled to claim the correctness of their individual perspectives.

Now, to my question. Imagine that the experiment is set up so that there is a single hook above the tunnel, aligned to its midpoint. The two doors are suspended from this hook by cables of identical length as measured by laying them side by side upon the ground or on the train. When the control is activated the hook releases both cables in one instant. As the release of both doors is simultaneous in both frames, would it not follow that the two doors must also close simultaneously, thus giving preference to the reference frame of Ground Observer as being the only correct perspective regardless of the measurements of the train observer?

Comment: " As the release of both doors is simultaneous in both frames,".  The relevant space is one dimensional, so two distinct events can't be simultaneous in two different frames.

Answer (score 15):

> When the control is activated the hook releases both cables in one instant. As the release of both doors is simultaneous in both frames

It doesn't work that way. Upon release of the hook the door does not immediately begin to close. The release of the hook relieves the tension in the hook-end of the cable immediately, but the tension on the door-end of the cable remains. That tension on the door-end of the cable keeps the door from closing even though the tension on the hook-end of the cable is gone.

The tension releases as a mechanical wave which propagates through the cable at the speed of sound in the cable. This is fast from a human perspective, but much much slower than the speed of light. Furthermore, the speed of the wave in the train frame is obtained by relativistic velocity addition. This leads, as in the original scenario, to the doors dropping non-simultaneously.

There is no mechanism or configuration that you can possibly arrange which will avoid this. What is simultaneous in one frame is non-simultaneous in another frame.

Comment: Ok so what if instead of a doors we have something like an electronic shutter which causes the "doors" to open or close at the speed of light (something like an LCD switching between clear and opaque, only faster) and instead of a train we have some kind of material that can only pass through the gate when it's not opaque? (it seems this is the only relevant part: "the speed of the wave in the train frame is obtained by relativistic velocity addition.")

Comment: @Michael it doesn’t matter what signal propagation method you use. Any signal will have the same final result. This is not a feature of specific technology, it is a feature of spacetime. Any technology operates in spacetime and so has the same end result.